# Check if same user is logged in from another device ( web or mobile)

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I am using CakePhp4 and Authentication Plugin.
 I have no clue for both.
**What I want to achieve**
 When a user logs in, determine if that user is already logged in using another device then either prompt the user or logout the user 
**What I tried?**

1. Followed this [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html)
2. Stored Session in database. Did exactly [this](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions)
3. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65788521/cakephp-4-2-get-logged-in-user-in-beforesave) might be a step in my objective but still no use.

**What I couldn't do?**
 I made a custom session handler but the code is not affecting any thing.
 Any hint is appreciated.